# How to set values for the silverlight plugin using javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, param, createobject, silverlight-plugin

I can't seem to figure out how to set a particular value for the Silverlight Plug-in. Specifically, the splashScreenSource value. I'm able to get this working using the param (name/value) method, however, I'm injecting the Silverlight plug-in using JavaScript and therefore not sure how I can get the plug-in to recognize that I do in fact want to use a splashscreen.

It doesn't appear that I can set the value using the args list provided via the default Silverlight.js file.

`Silverlight.createObject( source , parentElement , id , properties , events , initParams , userContext );`

Any idea's will be greatly appreciated,

thanks much,

Comment: previous questions? there was no answer except what AnthonyWJones provided yesterday.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/296895/gcadmes 5 Questions asked 1 Accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties parameter is expected to be a JavaScript object whose properties match the set of param names with a few additions such as width and height. So you can pass the following object to properties parameter.

```
var properties = {splashscreensource: "splash.xaml"};
```